# How can I write enable the /boot folder so I can easily share files between my PC and my Pi?

Tags: permissions

If I put the Pi SD card in my windows PC, its easy to transfer files to the boot drive. These files can seen in the Pi in the /boot folder.

However I want to transfer files back to the PC from the Pi easily.

Is there a way to write enable the /boot folder, or at least a folder inside /boot ?

Comment: By default boot is not write protected on Pi OS images. You will need admin (root) rights to access it though.

Comment: Use WinSCP or Filezilla to get files using ssh across your network.

Comment: Technically root can create a writable directory for the pi user there but as per existing answer, this is not a good idea.

Comment: The boot folder is part of the system folder. It is a bad idea to use it for exchanging files between Windows and the Pi. It is like opening the hood of your car engine and putting clothes inside. There is some space between the engine and the radiator. It does not mean you should put your clothes in that space and then start your car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I achieved a large writeable boot partition.

Make boot writeable - edit /etc/fstab to mount vfat as rw
Increase size of boot - using gparted, but I needed to do it on a different pi.

I now have a nice large writeable boot partition.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad idea.

- The `/boot` partition is rather small, so you cannot transfer large files
- You must shutdown the Pi before removing the SD card.
- The Pi's contact points on the SD card are not suited for regular removing and putting back the SD card
- If you keep the Pi's OS current, then the extra room on `/boot` will also be used partly.

So what to do?

- If you have a network, then `winscp` or something comparable is a better solution
- Otherwise, use a separate USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

The boot partition is FAT which does not support permissions.

The contents inherit permissions from the mount point (which is owned by root).

There is no need for this to be mounted for normal operation (only upgrade accesses it).

You could unmount and remount under a different directory owned by pi but as others have mentioned this is a poor idea as the partition is small and should not be used for storage.